# Items leaving the viewport when i add new code

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

Im currently working on my portfolio and every time i try to add new code/items to my sections the current items get pushed up to the top and out of the viewport. im not sure whats effecting my code to make this happen. Im working with JSX and i feel like the issue is with my app.js and app.css which dictates the whole react app. this is my current css

```
html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body{
  height: 300vh;
  overflow: auto;

  background: #136a8a;   /*fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #267871,
    #136a8a
    );  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #267871,
    #136a8a
      ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

  color: black
}

.pages{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -40%);
  font-size: 5rem;
}

/* .scroll{
  padding: 12px;
  height: 2000px;
} */



 @media only screen and (max-width:1322px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    padding-top: 1px;
  }
 }
@media only screen and (max-width:900px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
  }
} 
@media only screen and (max-width:700px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
} 
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
} 
@media only screen and (max-width:400px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
} 
@media only screen and (max-width:280px){
  .pages{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
}
```

I thought it had something to do with the height not being enough but it doesn't matter how high I put it it fails. also it might be the positioning but i tried to make the top in positioning more but it messes with a lot of things, I already catered most of my code around this positioning please help. thank you!